# JQuery slideDown slideUp button

Tags: jquery, button, slidedown, slideup

I have a script that will expand and collapse elements - and I added the Collapse / Expand all items. But if one member is deployed and click expand all - it will minimized / slideUp

How to write code to minimize and maximize whatever is expanded or collapsed elements?

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\"> 
$(document).ready(function ($){
        $('.splLink').click(function(){  
            $(this).parent().children('div.splCont').slideToggle('normal');



            if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
                $(this).parent('.cat-root').removeClass('active-h2');
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).parent('.name').removeClass('active-name');
                }
            else {
                $(this).parent('.cat-root').addClass('active-h2');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $(this).parent('.name').addClass('active-name');
                }
            return false;
        });




});
        function showAll(){

            $('.splLink').parent().children('div.splCont').slideToggle('normal');

            if ( $('.splLink').hasClass('active') ) {

                $('.splLink').parent('.cat-root').removeClass('active-h2');
                $('.splLink').removeClass('active');
                $('.splLink').parent('.name').removeClass('active-name');
                $('.btn').html('Развернуть');
                }
            else {

                $('.splLink').parent('.cat-root').addClass('active-h2');
                $('.splLink').addClass('active');
                $('.splLink').parent('.name').addClass('active-name');
                $('.btn').html('Свернуть');
                }

            return false;
            }

</script>
```

Comment: _"curdle"_? Are we dealing with milk here?

Comment: minimized / slideUp elements.. pardon my French

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($("div.splCont:visible").length > $("div.splCont:hidden").length) {
  $('.splLink').parent().children('div.splCont').slideUp('normal');
} else {
  $('.splLink').parent().children('div.splCont').slideDown('normal');
}
```

If the number of visible elements is greater than the number hidden, then everything will slide up and be collapsed. Otherwise, everything will slide down and be shown.